# Enable And Disable element rules

Tags: jquery

I have to enable and disable a element rules in run time, anyone knows how can i do that? I tried to do something like $(element).rules('disable'), but this don't work fine.

Comment: And what code are you working with? (X)HTML, jQuery..? And, incidentally, I don't think that there is a jQuery method `.rules()`.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `.rules()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the validator plugin, there's a `"remove"` option for the `.rules()` method.

```
.rules("remove");
```

or you can pass which rules to remove as a space-separated string of names as a second argument.

Comment: if I remove a rule, i have to recreate a rule again. I need something to reusable

Comment: José Silva: Is it that in some cases you don't want the validation to prevent a submit? There may be a way around that.